# How to suspend my app?

Tags: android

I have an app that spends a lot of time generating bitmaps for use as wallpaper. When the user has selected a bitmap and applied it, I would like to go to the main launcher screen so it can be seen "for real".

I could just exit the app when the selection is made, but I would like to maintain state at least for a short time so that if the user wants to go right back in to change cropping or select a different bitmap, things are as they were before.

Andy ideas? Is there an Intent I could use to get back to the main launcher screen? Maybe simulate the "Home" button being pressed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An intent to go to Home:

```
    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

    startActivity(homeIntent);
```